# Windows live loging is same on 2 computers I must return one to service, can I change its login

Tags: windows-8

My monitor is broken on a laptop and it is being returned for warranty, the problem is it uses the same windowslive account as our separate main computer.  Can I now change the password on the broken laptop so the repair service doesn't have access to my active Windows live account - just the broken laptop hard drive?  Where do I make that change if it is possible.

Comment: You don't have an hdmi port on the laptop and a tv screen you could plug it into do you?

Comment: no @jayson but I am trying to use your idea to "see that machine"  I have also been learning and it appears I need to disassociate that machine with my windows account correct?

Comment: @willowvalley - Unless you configured to automatically log into the account, they would need to know your password to log into the account, which they don't need to replace the monitor.  If all you do is restart the machine you will, log out of your Microsoft Account, which will require a password to log back into.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to make sure is if you can borrow another computer, just log into your windows live account and change your password.  Your laptops credentials will then no longer be valid regardless of if it automatically logs in or not.

Comment: Credentials will still be chached locally - if they don't connect the system to the internet first, auto-login to the system could still work. Then again, we're already talking about someone with physical access - so most options for protecting local system access are pretty much gone. This should still work to protect the Live account itself though.